# Affine and projective geometry book question

Tags: projective-geometry, affine-geometry

Question: Consider a curve of the form $y=f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of positive degree $n$. Prove that the curve has exactly one point $P$ at infinity, that it intersects every vertical line exactly $n-1$ times at $P$, and that it intersects the line at infinity exactly $n$ times at $P$.
(The case $n=1$ may require separate consideration.)

I have tried many times now but Im completely lost on this one because I want to do it right with no wrongs.

How to do this whole problem step by step?

Comment: I don’t get it. What is the point of saying you tried many times with without mentioning what you did even for one? You should probably tell us what your most promising attempt looked like, and then help will be easier.

Comment: Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$, with $a_n\neq0$. The points $[x:y:z]$ on the curve satisfy $z^{n-1}y-a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}z-...-a_0z^n=0$. The points on the line at infinity are those with $z=0$. Of these, to be on the curve the would satisfy $-a_nx^n=0$. So the only point at infinity and on the curve is $P=[0:1:0]$.

Comment: A vertical line is of the form $x-cz=0$, for some constant $c$. In the chart $y\neq0$, which contains $P$, the ideal of the intersection is generated by $x-cz$ and $z^{n-1}(1-zf(c))$. The order of the intersection is $I(x-cz,z^{n-1}(1-zf(c)))=I(x-cz,z^{n-1})+I(x-cz,1-zf(c))=(n-1)I(x-cz,z)+I(x-cz,1-zf(c))=(n-1)I(x,z)+I(x-cz,1-zf(c))=n-1+I(x-cz,1-zf(c))$. At $P$, $1-zf(c)=1\neq0$. Therefore, $I(x-cz,1-zf(c))=0$. Therefore, the intersection multiplicity of the curve with the line $x-cz$ at $P$ is $n-1$.

Comment: On the same $y\neq0$ chart, the line at infinity is $z=0$. The intersection with the curve has order $I(z,z^{n-1}-a_nx^{n}-...-a_0z^n)=I(z,a_nx^n)=nI(z,x)=n$.